# Table View not shown in Interface Builder Attributes of a NSTableView in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, tableview, nstableview

When viewing the attributes of a NSTableView table in Xcode 5, only Scroll View and View appears, whereas in tutorials online I should be accessing the Table View.

I need to access the items in Table View, such as number of columns, etc.
I have searched the internet but couldn't see a reason why this does not appear.
Do the options to change columns etc appear in a different location than in Xcode 4?

Screenshot:

[image: http://imgur.com/g4vE5wR]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the tableview is embedded in a scrollview and a clipview which makes it hard to click.

select it by using your sidebar on the left

[image]